# JBoss client and endorsed lib have stax-api.jar that conflicts with POI 3.11 XML jars

Tags: jboss, apache-poi, stax

I am having issues with stax-api.jar presence in these folders..

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37)
```

If I get rid of the stax-api.jar, which shouldn't have caused any trouble in the first place since JBoss announced that these jars are not necessary and not bundled anymore because JDK1.6 has the requisite functionality, I land up with another set of problems, JBoss doesn't start up..

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container configuration not found: CTS Message Driven Bean available: {Clustered CMPEntityBean=org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.ContainerConfigurationMetaDataWrapper@300dec94{Clustered CMP EntityBean}, Instance Per Transaction CMP EntityBean=org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.ContainerConfigurationMetaDataWrapper@59edf8fd{Instance Per Transaction CMP EntityBean}, Singleton Message Driven ...
...
```

...
Anybody resolve the stax jar conflicts in JBoss, please?

Comment: What happens if you upgrade to Apache POI 3.12?

Comment: Interesting question, Gagravarr. We went back to 3.8 which helped us get out of the classloading issues but I think I will have to give 3.12 a try and see how that goes. Looks like the lightning speeds of 3.11 are not quite there in 3.11 and my exports take forever. Thank you